# Do HibernateDaoSupport in spring require hibernate jar files for support

Tags: java

I am using `spring 2.5` with `HibernateDaoSupport`. My doubt is, do I still require `Hibernate jar` files for support of `HibernateDaoSupport`.

I did a sample example in netbeans. I unchecked the `hibernate jar` library and the application is still working.

But is it correctly working with the `HibernateDaoSupport` class without using Hibernate jar files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HibernateDaoSupport is present in Spring jars. It is used to provide support to Hibernate-based data access objects. If you plan in using Hibernate for read/write into DB, you will require the hibernate jar.

Please check out the following link for more details:

http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html

Comment: @Vipul If this answer helped you, you could check the answer as correct to.  Just thick the green check under the upvote counter

Answer (score 0):

you need to put org.springframework.orm_x.x.x.RELEASE.jar file in your project